# mystile fatal error call to a member function is_visible() on a non-object

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woothemes

Wordpress version: 3.5.2
Woocommerce version: 2.0.13

Following is the code that is giving the error. The code is of product search. Although the function reads search by tag it doesn't. It searches based on other criterias taken from the checkboxes and drop down menus. In the code below, I've mentioned the line because of which the error started, by commenting besides it.

```
add_filter('the_posts', 'search_by_product_tag');

function search_by_product_tag($posts, $query = false)
{
//var_dump($_GET);
//$new_posts = array();
if($_GET['sh']=='search')
{
    $search_tags = array(
        'destination' => $_GET['destination'], 
        'days' => $_GET['days'],
        'budget' => $_GET['budget']
    );
    //var_dump($search_tags);die();
    $ignoreIds = array(0);
    foreach($posts as $post)
    {
        $ignoreIds[] = $post->ID;
    }
    $matchedTags = get_post_by_tag($search_tags, $ignoreIds);
    //var_dump($matchedTags);
    if ($matchedTags) 
    {
        foreach($matchedTags as $product_id)
        {   
            $posts[] = get_posts($product_id->object_id);
        }
    }
    return $posts;  
}
if($_GET['f']=='filter')
 {
    //$filter_tags = array(
        if(isset($_GET['price'])){
            $price_range = $_GET['price'];  
            $price = $price_range;
        }
        else{
            $price = "";
        }

        if(isset($_GET['holiday'])){
            $holiday_type = $_GET['holiday'];   
            $holiday = implode("','", $holiday_type);
        }
        else{
            $holiday = "";
        }

        if(isset($_GET['tour'])){
            $tour_category = $_GET['tour']; 
            $tour = implode("','", $tour_category);
        }
        else{
            $tour = "";
        }
    /*$ignoreIds = array(0);
    foreach($posts as $post)
    {
        $ignoreIds[] = $post->ID;
    }*/
    $new_post = array();
    //$matchedTags = get_post_by_filter_tag($price_range,$holiday_type,$tour_category, $ignoreIds);
    $matchedTags = get_post_by_filter_tag($price,$holiday,$tour, $ignoreIds);
    //var_dump($matchedTags);die();
    if ($matchedTags) 
    {
        foreach($matchedTags as $product_id)
        {   
            $new_post[] = get_posts($product_id->ID); //Error was given after I added this line instead of the default given below
            //$posts[] = get_post($product_id->id);
        }
    }
    return $new_post;
    die();
}

return $posts;
}
function get_post_by_tag($tags, $ignoreIds) 
{
//Check for 
global $wpdb, $wp_query;
$ignoreIdsForMySql = implode(",", $ignoreIds);
//var_dump($ignoreIdsForMySql);

//dynamic query
$query = "select distinct tr.object_id from $wpdb->terms t
        inner join $wpdb->term_taxonomy tt on t.term_id = tt.term_id
        inner join $wpdb->term_relationships tr on tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id
        inner join $wpdb->posts p on p.ID = tr.object_id
        inner join $wpdb->postmeta pm on p.ID = pm.post_id
        and t.name IN ('".$tags['destination']."','".$tags['days']."')
        where pm.meta_key = '_price' and pm.meta_value = '".$tags['budget']."'
        and p.post_status = 'publish'
        and p.post_type = 'product'
        and (p.post_parent = 0 or p.post_parent is null);";    
//var_dump($query);
//Search for the sku of a variation and return the parent.
$matchedProducts = $wpdb->get_results($query) ;

//var_dump($matchedProducts);
if(is_array($matchedProducts) && !empty($matchedProducts))
{
    //var_dump($matchedProducts);
    $wp_query->found_posts += sizeof($matchedProducts);
    //var_dump($wp_query->found_posts, sizeof($matchedProducts));
    return $matchedProducts;

}

//return get_post($product_id);

return null;
}

//function get_post_by_filter_tag($price_range,$holiday_type,$tour_category,$ignoreIds)    {
function get_post_by_filter_tag($price,$holiday,$tour,$ignoreIds)
{
//Check for 
global $wpdb, $wp_query;
//$ignoreIdsForMySql = implode(",", $ignoreIds);
/*$price = $price_range;
$holiday = implode("','", $holiday_type);
$tour = implode("','", $tour_category);*/
//var_dump($ignoreIdsForMySql);

//dynamic query
$query = "select distinct p.ID from $wpdb->terms t
        inner join $wpdb->term_taxonomy tt on t.term_id = tt.term_id
        inner join $wpdb->term_relationships tr on tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id
        inner join $wpdb->posts p on p.ID = tr.object_id
        inner join $wpdb->postmeta visibility on p.ID = visibility.post_id    
        and visibility.meta_key = '_visibility'
        and (visibility.meta_value = 'visible' or visibility.meta_value ='search')
        inner join $wpdb->postmeta pm on p.ID = pm.post_id
        and t.name IN ('".$holiday."','".$tour."')
        where pm.meta_key = '_price' and pm.meta_value <= $price
        and p.post_status = 'publish'
        and p.post_type = 'product'
        and (p.post_parent = 0 or p.post_parent is null);";  

//Search for the sku of a variation and return the parent.
$matchedProducts = $wpdb->get_results($query) ;

var_dump($matchedProducts);//die();
if(is_array($matchedProducts) && !empty($matchedProducts))
{
    //var_dump($matchedProducts);
    $wp_query->found_posts += sizeof($matchedProducts);
    //var_dump($wp_query->found_posts, sizeof($matchedProducts));
    //var_dump($wp_query);
    return $matchedProducts;

}

//return get_post($product_id);

return null;
}
```

Comment: php is case sensitive when it comes to variables. id and ID are two different variables.

Comment: yes I'm aware of that. The query is running perfectly fine. Returns the correct ID. So I assume that isn't the issue.